# Cannot resolve symbol addFormDataPart

Tags: java, okhttp

```
MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("title", "title");  
                builder.addFormDataPart("contact",  "9876543210");
```

I am using okhttp 3.9.0 ( 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0')